# using fswebcam and fbi to display images

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a small project with my raspberry pi. I have a webcam and a [piTFT](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1601) display. I want to write a shell script that iteratively uses the webcam to take a picture, and then display the picture on the piTFT. I want to run the script via SSH.

I have had success in doing so, using [fswebcam](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fswebcam.1.html) to capture the image, and [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fbi.1.html) to display the image on the piTFT. The script is simple: run a while loop (until a keypress), and on each iteration take a picture and display it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi

count=0
keypress=''
while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do

    # update console
    let count+=1
    echo ---------Taking image $count---------

    # take picture
    fswebcam -r 320x240 -q image.jpg

    # display on PITFT
    sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 --noverbose -a image.jpg

    sleep 0.1 
    keypress="`cat -v`"
done

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
exit 0
```

**Here's the problem:** i have tried everything i can think of to get fbi to run 'quietly' (using the noverbose option, etc), but i still get this line in the console:

```
using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

Is there a way to suppress this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redirect `fbi` `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 --noverbose -a image.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1
```